# Template and BST

Tags: c++, templates, syntax, binary-search-tree

The template declaration is:

```
template <typename DataType>
class BST
```

and the error that I keep getting is
bst.h(101) : see reference to class template instantiation 'BST::BinNode' being compiled
bst.h(183) : see reference to class template instantiation 'BST' being compiled

I think my syntax may be wrong, but I'm not sure what about it is. Could somebody push me into the right direction. I just cannot get it to compile. Class BinNode is a private class of the main class BST. The line the error is referring too is DataType BinNode::treeheight(BinNode * p)

```
private:
/***** Node class *****/
class BinNode 
{
 public:

DataType data;
BinNode * left;
BinNode * right;
DataType treeheight(BinNode * p);

template <typename DataType>
DataType BinNode::treeheight(BinNode * p)
{
    if(p != 0)
    {
        int heightl = treeheight(p->left);
        int heightr = treeheight(p->right);
    }

    if(heightl > heightr)
        return heightl;

    else
        return height r;
}
```

Comment: `BinNode` isn't a template, but you're defining its member function as if it were declared as a template. Moreover, a qualified member function definition (`BinNode::treeheight(…) {…}`) doesn't go inside the class body as it looks like you've done here. Place it outside the class.

Comment: Is the `Node` class a template? If so, when defining the member function (outside the class, that is), you need to qualify the member function definition as `Node<DataType>::BinNode::treeheight(…) {…}` since `BinNode` is a nested class of `Node`.

Comment: I assumed it was because it used DataType for the data variable, but thats the only indicator thats it part of the template

Comment: So if `Node` is a template, then the definition of `treenode()` should be qualified with `Node<DataType>::BinNode::`.

Comment: Its working, thanks for the help, im trying to figure out how to make the question answered

Answer (score 0):

When defining the member function (outside the class, that is), you need to qualify the member function definition as `Node<DataType>::BinNode::treeheight(…) {…}` since `BinNode` is a nested class of `Node`.